# Determining whether precipitation will occur or not and finding the concentration of a specific ion in a solution

Tags: equilibrium, solubility, concentration, precipitation

[image: The Question]

The Ksp value of AY2 = 9.148 x 10^-2. I am having problem with calculating the concentration of ions. And without the correct concentration I can't find the Qsp/Kip so I'm stuck without them I can't determine whether the new solution will precipitate or not. How to calculate the concentration of ions in this type of scenario?

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of essential parts. 
// Optionally, here are formatting guides for [texts](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) and [formulas/equations/expressions](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: 1/ Enumerate initial concentrations 2/ Involve variable of amount of precipitated salt 3/ express ion concentrations as function of this variable. 4/ Formulate and resolve equation involving Ksp and ion concentrations.

Comment: whoami - determine separate ions concentrations in the starting solutions, then use the dilution equation: $$\ce{m_1 * V_1 = m_2 * V_2}$$ to get concentrations in the mixed solution.